# Out of memory while decoding Image using Base64 Decode

Tags: android

I'm getting image data from a server and I'm converting it to byte[] using Base64.decode. My code works fine for small image sizes but for a particular image of size 9.2MB, it crashes. I have read about down sampling in various posts but before I could get to the sampling section of code, I'm getting a out of memory exception while reading the bytes in the following line of code.
byte[] data = Base64.decode(attchData[i].getBytes(),0);

Please help me out.

Comment: you convert big images to small image that will avoid ur problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this methood, May work for you

```
    decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(src, reqWidth, reqHeight);
```

use this implementation

```
 public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input stream you are reading from (when reading data from the server) in a [Base64InputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html) instead. This should reduce the amount of memory required during the base64 decoding phase.

But you should check if you really have to send images of that size to the client. Maybe the images can be scaled on the server side?

Comment: And why are the images base64-encoded in the first place? Is that really necessary?